# Updating an NSTextField while controlling an NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField, where I can perform a search, and the search results are displayed in an NSTableView. I'd like to be able to either use the keyboard up/down arrow keys or click with the mouse to select an item in the table view without the text field losing focus. Basically, I'd like to have it behave similarly to Spotlight:

[image: gif showing how the Spotlight allows text editing while being able to select an item from the results]

As you can see, Spotlight lets me select items in the list using the keyboard arrow keys or the mouse, but I can still continue typing into the search field without it losing focus the whole time. It feels as if both the text field and the list below are focused at the same time.

I've gone through similar SO questions like this one:
[Filtering NSTable while typing into NSTextField - auto-select first row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48481006/)

Currently, I'm only able to have the keyboard focus on either the text field or the table view. I'm listening for up/down arrow keys and updating the table view's selected index accordingly:

```swift
// called when the down arrow key is pressed in the text field
func focusNextItem() {
    let selectedRow = min(tableView.selectedRow + 1, results.count - 1)
    tableView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: selectedRow), byExtendingSelection: false)
    tableView.scrollRowToVisible(selectedRow)
}

// called when the up arrow key is pressed in the text field
func focusPreviousItem() {
    let selectedRow = max(tableView.selectedRow - 1, 0)
    tableView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: selectedRow), byExtendingSelection: false)
    tableView.scrollRowToVisible(selectedRow)
}
```

However, the table remains unfocused (greyed out) until it is clicked with the mouse. How would I have it behave similarly to the Spotlight example, ie., both the table view and the text field (seem) to have focus all the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSTextField with auto-suggestions like Safari's address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674992/nstextfield-with-auto-suggestions-like-safaris-address-bar) Having "Child window" is the answer

Comment: @MarekH Ah, thanks for sharing that. I saw a similar solution in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iuHMd0-8BI. Can this child window be made transparent so that it doesn't feel like a separate window?

Comment: The youtube link uses same solution - "addChildWindow". You can customize child window as you like. (backgroungcolor transparent etc.)